# XPages: set up SourceTree for two databases as branches

Tags: version-control, xpages, atlassian-sourcetree, domino-designer-eclipse

Just starting (again) with SourceTree on a fairly big XPages application.

We have two databases we use for development: one is the gold version database, the other is the development database. When we have to fix something, it often has to be done in both databases.

So, I would like to use SourceTree locally for both databases, in such a way that both databases can co-exist while using the same repository, as branches, and that changes in the main code are transported automatically to the other database.

Is that doable? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you only use source control (and SourceTree) with the development database and that you then update the gold version database using the development database as template.

Comment: Sorry, my explanation is probably somewhat faulty. There are two different branches, in two databases that have originally the same base. Both databases are maintained separately. The dev db has some elements that are completely different from the same elements in the gold database. If possible I want to have both versions active and open in the Designer, not really required, but I'd hate to extract the gold version over and over again when I have to repair something. So, essentially, they are two templates albeit with 95% of the elements identical. Is there a solution?

Comment: A more difficult question would be how to add the existing applications to one single repository...

Comment: You can have a branch for each db in your Git repo. You can then check out each branch as a separate repo in SourceTree and then assign each db in Domino Designer to the relevant repo on disk. So it's indeed possible.

Comment: I agree with Per. Standard practice for source control, as defined by Git Flow, is a single branch at any one time. If a fix is required, commit any un-committed work (if any, but there shouldn't be). Then create a hotfix branch, synch with ODP, develop the hotfix, test, build (i.e. create a Template), and complete the hotfix, which merges back into master and develop. Every developer has his / her own instance - so separate local NSFs, so there is no impact on others. If you do need two separate NSFs, sync everything on NSF A, commit, remove the link from NSF A to the ODP. Then link to NSF B.

Comment: Develop, test, build for deployment, syncing NSF B to ODP. Do all this in your alternate branch. At the end, remove the link from NSF B to the ODP, switch branches again and re-link to NSF A. This would probably be the standard approach for source control, outside of Domino.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat this like 2 different branches, you can in fact have 2 different branches open at the same time, you just need to set up 2 different projects of the same repository in sourcetree (that are in different folder locations).
So to be clear this is the same repository but cloned in different locations.

Then these projects should have 'remotes' set up to one another. You can then push/pull from one remote to another. (Or if this is too complicated you can just push up to origin and then pull down from origin into the other project)

This allows you to keep these 2 projects checked out with different branches.

I have done this myself because I need to develop the same project in 2 different environments at the same time.

You then just need to figure out a good strategy for merging changes from one branch to another. One good strategy might be just to keep your commits very small and 'atomic' you can then use cherry-pick to choose which commits to apply to the other branch.

Let me know if you have any more questions

Just as a side note: there should be no problem having 2 databases in one repository if you go down that other oute. We have about 15-20 templates in our one big repository.
Just put the On Disk Project in different sub folders e.g.

```
.git/
goldodp/
devodp/
```